# SharePoint Picture library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, picture-library

I have created a picture library in SharePoint 2013 site. When i move cursor over an image by default it shows file name, height x width, file size. Is it possible to remove these fields and show a custom field. ( i have a field "event" and want to show the event name).

[image]